# Show that a graph contains two trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> If a graph $G$ with $n\ge2$ vertices and $n-2$ edges does not contain
> any isolated vertices, show that at least two components of the graph
> are trees (with at least two vertices each).

We know that a graph is a tree iff it does not contain cycles and has $n-1$ edges. But how could we combine this to provide a solution for the above?

Comment: Did you try inducting on $n$? $n=4$ case is obvious, for example. For general $n$, you might want to look at a vertex of degree $1$, and remove it from the graph.

Comment: Suppose the $i^\text{th}$ component of $G$ has $n_i$ vertices and $e_i$ edges. You know that $\sum(e_i-n_i)=(n-2)-n=-2$ and you know that $e_i-n_i\ge-1$ for each $i$. Can you prove from that that there are at least two $i$ with $e_i-n_i=-1$?

Comment: You do know that a connected graph on $n$ vertices has at least $n-1$ edges, and a connected graph on $n$ vertices with exactly $n-1$ edges is a tree?

Comment: @bof Yeah sure.

Comment: Good. Then you see how my first comment completely answers your question.